# Bug report: "next" button in search changes the search term

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

1. Go to the Stackoverflow home page.
2. Type into the search box:

   utf-16
3. Press enter
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the page.
5. Click "Next"

The page that comes up is https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=utf26&page=2&tab=relevance as though my search term was "utf26" not "utf-16"

This may have something to do with a previous search I did, for "ucs-2" I don't know.

Firefox 3.0.11, Windows XP

Comment: @Matrix: This is the right place.

Comment: OK, I just performed another search and it seems to work correctly now. Marking as completed.

Comment: If no one objects, I'm closing the question, as I'm pretty sure this has been resolved.

Comment: @Kyle: Not resolved. I just did the OP's steps and reproduced the error. Chrome 2.0.172.33, Windows XP.

Comment: This is perplexing... it WAS working, and now it's not. Oh, well, reopened and rolled back. Argh.

Comment: @Kyle: I'm having one of those days, too :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the page boxes are incrementing.

Page 2 is utf26
Page 3 is utf36
Page 4 is utf46
etc..

Comment: Niiice              !